# OpenCV - adding variable to class member crashes program

Tags: c++, memory-management, opencv, stdvector

I have a bit of a headache trying to understand why simply adding a member variable to OpenCV's Point_ class makes my program crash. This is one of the classes which comes with OpenCV to store 2D points. If you edit opencv2/core/core.hpp and add a member variable to the class Point_, then the program crashes. See my member variable comment as a comment:

```
template<typename _Tp> class CV_EXPORTS Point_
{
public:
typedef _Tp value_type;

// various constructors
Point_();
Point_(_Tp _x, _Tp _y);
Point_(const Point_& pt);
Point_(const CvPoint& pt);
Point_(const CvPoint2D32f& pt);
Point_(const Size_<_Tp>& sz);
Point_(const Vec<_Tp, 2>& v);

Point_& operator = (const Point_& pt);
//! conversion to another data type
template<typename _Tp2> operator Point_<_Tp2>() const;

//! conversion to the old-style C structures
operator CvPoint() const;
operator CvPoint2D32f() const;
operator Vec<_Tp, 2>() const;

//! dot product
_Tp dot(const Point_& pt) const;
//! dot product computed in double-precision arithmetics
double ddot(const Point_& pt) const;
//! checks whether the point is inside the specified rectangle
bool inside(const Rect_<_Tp>& r) const;

_Tp x, y; //< the point coordinates
//OCR Additions
bool iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork;
};
```

Its not just adding a bool. It could be anything like an 'int i' as a member variable.

```
BoundingBox(vector<vector<cv::Point> > &contourPoints, vector<Vec4i> &hierarchy, Mat &imgSrc)
{
    currentContour=0;
    nextContour=0;
    maxContour=0;
    //Is is related to the shallow copy???
    this->contourPoints= contourPoints;  //<----- starts crashing here
    this->hierarchy=hierarchy;
    this->imgSrc = imgSrc;
}
```

So the runtime exception I get is:

"Debug Assertion Failed!"
"Expression: vector iterator not dereferencable"

I am WTF on this. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

Additional info(Stack Trace):

```
>   msvcp100d.dll!std::_Debug_message(const wchar_t * message=0x00fac0b0, const wchar_t * file=0x00fabb60, unsigned int line=70)  Line 15   C++
OCR.exe!std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >::operator*()  Line 70 + 0x14 bytes    C++
OCR.exe!std::_Uninit_copy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >,cv::Point_<int> *,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _First={x=-1414812757 y=-17891602 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=false }, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _Last={x=-33686019 y=-1414812757 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true }, cv::Point_<int> * _Dest=0x00b51520, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > & _Al={...}, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag __formal={...})  Line 376 + 0x8 bytes   C++
OCR.exe!std::_Uninitialized_copy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >,cv::Point_<int> *,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _First={x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true }, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _Last={x=-33686019 y=-1414812757 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true }, cv::Point_<int> * _Dest=0x00b51070, std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > & _Al={...})  Line 414 + 0x73 bytes    C++
OCR.exe!std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::_Ucopy<std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >(std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _First={x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true }, std::_Vector_const_iterator<std::_Vector_val<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > _Last={x=-33686019 y=-1414812757 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true }, cv::Point_<int> * _Ptr=0x00b51070)  Line 1318 + 0x58 bytes   C++
OCR.exe!std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >(const std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > & _Right=[99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...))  Line 539 + 0x57 bytes  C++
OCR.exe!std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >::construct<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > &>(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Ptr=0x00b93b40 [0](), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > & _Val=[99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...))  Line 208 + 0x3c bytes   C++
OCR.exe!std::_Cons_val<std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > >,std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > &>(std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > & _Alval={...}, std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Pdest=0x00b93b40 [0](), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > & _Src=[99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...))  Line 281   C++
OCR.exe!std::_Uninit_copy<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > *,std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > *,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _First=0x00b4d570 [99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Last=0x00b4d7dc [0](), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Dest=0x00b93b40 [0](), std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > & _Al={...}, std::_Nonscalar_ptr_iterator_tag __formal={...})  Line 376 + 0x11 bytes C++
OCR.exe!std::_Uninitialized_copy<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > *,std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > *,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _First=0x00b4d570 [99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Last=0x00b4d7dc [0](), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Dest=0x00b93b40 [0](), std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > & _Al={...})  Line 414 + 0x33 bytes   C++
OCR.exe!std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >::_Ucopy<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > *>(std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _First=0x00b4d570 [99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Last=0x00b4d7dc [0](), std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > * _Ptr=0x00b93b40 [0]())  Line 1318 + 0x18 bytes  C++
OCR.exe!std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > >::operator=(const std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > > & _Right=[31]([99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...),...,...))  Line 739 + 0x1d bytes    C++
OCR.exe!BoundingBox::BoundingBox(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > > & contourPoints=[31]([99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...),...,...), std::vector<cv::Vec<int,4>,std::allocator<cv::Vec<int,4> > > & hierarchy=[31]({...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}), cv::Mat & imgSrc={...})  Line 29  C++
OCR.exe!OCRBase::processImage(std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > >,std::allocator<std::vector<cv::Point_<int>,std::allocator<cv::Point_<int> > > > > & contourPoints=[31]([99]({x=121 y=87 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=119 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=118 y=89 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=116 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=92 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=93 y=113 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=113 y=91 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=90 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=114 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=111 y=88 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=88 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=90 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=91 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=93 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=94 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=96 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=97 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=99 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=100 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=102 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=103 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=105 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=106 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=108 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=109 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=111 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=112 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=114 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=115 y=110 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=110 y=117 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },{x=117 y=112 iAddedThisButItCrashesRemovingMeMakesItWork=true },...,...),...,...), std::vector<cv::Vec<int,4>,std::allocator<cv::Vec<int,4> > > & hierarchy=[31]({...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...},{...}), cv::Mat & imgSrc={...})  Line 10 + 0x3a bytes    C++
OCR.exe!main(int argc=2, char * * argv=0x00b4d228)  Line 35 C++
OCR.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes  C
OCR.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371  C
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please add more code. but for now try to make your own allocator and iterator

Comment: it seems you have to implement your iterator and allocator as it crashes when it tries to copy them I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I know the problem is in the iterator but I don't understand why when assigning a shallow copy from one vector to another would cause a problem in the iterator. It just doesn't make sense when adding a variable which would theoretically occupy just 4 more bytes would just die. As far as implementing my own iterator and allocator, I'll stay away from that for now :)

Comment: it is not a shallow copy it will copy all the elements.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. You are right, it is making a deep copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix this problem please use this data type instead

```
Vector<cv::mat>
```

Comment: Did you try this out? Changing to from 'vector' to 'Vector' causes a lot of re-factoring in my code since OpenCV's version of vector is different than std C++.

Comment: I did not but I found that the OpenCV Mat and Point has their own allocator so when you make vector<mat> or vector<point> you should pass the class iterator too. I did not try it myself.

Comment: I see, but I think I will post my question directly to OpenCV discussion board and share an answer if I get a different one and if not just, take yours. I don't see how this breaks the iterator, since it works without adding the member variable.

Comment: I think adding my own custom iterator would solve the problem. I wanted to know internally why this failed so I got an answer from http://answers.opencv.org/question/1791/editing-corehpp-crashes-during-run-time/
which seems to support that doing your own custom iterator would solve the problem. Thanks again.

Comment: welcome, I was struggling when I started working on my master thesis with OpenCV but it helped me a lot actually and I decided not to play with the OpenCV code but I made my own classes for face detection and recognition.